# Compare two MySQL Datetime columns

Tags: mysql

I have two DATETIME columns in a MySQL table:

- CreatedDate
- PhotoModificationTimestamp

I'm able to compare the two columns successfully in a SELECT statement like this:

```
AND CreatedDate < PhotoModificationTimestamp
```

I need to change the comparison so that we allow a 12 hour period between the two dates.

So if `CreatedDate = 2018-01-23 00:00:00`
And `PhotoModificationTimestamp = 2018-01-23 06:59:44`

We would NOT return these records because they are within 12 hours of each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ... WHERE CreatedDate + INTERVAL 12 HOUR < PhotoModificationTimestamp
```

Answer (score 1):

This where statement would work:

```
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`PhotoModificationTimestamp`) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`CreatedDate`) >= 43200
```

where 43200 = 12 * 3600 seconds;

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `TIMESTAMPDIFF`

```
AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, PhotoModificationTimestamp, CreatedDate) > 12
```